# AWS RDS - Does downgrading a db instance class cause the existing data to lose?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a live database which is currently running in xlarge instance. For some reasons, I need to downgrade it to a lower one (medium or small). Is it possible by preserving all my existing data ?

Answer (score 10):

No, Downgrading DB instance Class on AWS RDS does not cause any data loss.
But as you have live DB instance, make sure you have created an **Image** of existing(live DB before the change) just in case you need backup.
I recommend (so does the AWS Documentation) that you test any changes on a test instance before modifying a production instance so you better understand the impact of a change.

Comment: You can also make a live read-only replica of your instance using the new instance type, and the promote it to a stand-alone master once you have confirmed that the data is intact.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the data is preserved in the instance class change. But if you would like to apply immediately this will have a downtime. To reduce the downtime make sure to Enable Multi-AZ feature, This will reduce your downtime when performing the instance class change.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How long is the downtime without Multi-AZ?